# Typescript : Create a generic type to mock private and protected method for testing

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to test the method `Test.returnOk()`

I have this type :

```
type Mock<T> = { [K in keyof T]: jest.Mock<unknown> } & T
```

It allows us to keep typing and to mock the method

```
// test.ts

class Test {
  public returnOk(){
    return this.getOk()
  }
  private getOk(){
    return 'ok'
  }
}

// test.spec.ts

describe('Test', () => {
  describe('returnOk', () => {
    it('should return "ok"', () =>{
      const expectedResult = 'ok stubed'

      const test = new Test() as Mock<Test>
      // Error : cannot access to protected / private methode
      test.getOk = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(expectedResult)

      const result = test.returnOk()
      expect(result).toBe(expectedResult)
    })
  })
})
```

The issue come from `[K in keyof T]`, protected and private methodes are not available in `keyof`

So I am trying to create a type that can take an array of private method to make available.

```
type MockWithPrivateMethod<T, X> = { [K in keyof T]: jest.Mock<unknown> } & T & { [Y in X]: jest.Mock<unknown> }

// called like this
const test = new Test() as MockWithPrivateMethod<Test, ['getOk']>

// won t work with an array (value), can work with an object but it s not beautiful
```

Comment: _"to mock private and protected method for testing"_ -- this completely misses the point of testing. **Do not** test methods (private or public, it doesn't matter). **Test the business requirements!** If it is difficult to identify the business requirements in a specific class then either the class is improperly designed or it is just a small component that does not need tests on its own. A test that describes the expected business behaviour of a component and not its implementation can help designing the component's interface and its collaboration with other components.

Comment: The work "unit" in "unit testing" does not mean "class". It means the smallest component whose behaviour can be reasoned about in regard with the business requirements. It could be a class, a function, a module but many times it is a combination of these.

Comment: I agree, but here, getOk() is in reality a method making a GET request (that should not be sent), so it s certainly my implementation that is not correct, but I wanted to know if such thing was possible in typescript

Comment: How does `getOk()` issues the request? If it uses another package you can probably mock that package (but [this is not a good idea](https://testing.googleblog.com/2020/07/testing-on-toilet-dont-mock-types-you.html)). Or you can extend the class in the test module and make `getOk()` public for the purpose of testing. Or mock it in another way. It is still not the way testing should be done but could solve your problem at hand.

Comment: Ok, I think I am trying to test something that don t need to be tested